# Can Delphi TField.OnValidate restore the original value without raising exception?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I usually implement validation logic as:

```
procedure TMyDM.IBQueryAMOUNTValidate(
  Sender: TField);
begin
  inherited;
  if Sender.AsFloat>100
    then raise Exception.Create('Amount is too large!');
end;
```

The question is - is there chance not to raise `Exception` in the `OnValidate` (which stops further processing), but to restore silently original value in the `OnValidate` and proceed with `OnChange`, `CheckBrowseMode` and all the GUI updates that are called by the `CheckBrowseMode`/`Post`?

Of course, I know that I can always replace `OnValidate` logic with `OnChange` logic that handles `OldValue` and `NewValue` but it seems to me that code would be cleaner it I stick with `OnValidate`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `OnValidate` to do anything apart from raise an exception to reject the
`Sender`'s value.

To see why, set up a simple test app consisting of a TClientDataSet with fields ID (Integer) and Name (String(20)), TDataSource,
TDBNavigator, TDBGrid and TDBEdit for the Name field.  Add the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.ClientDataSet1NameValidate(Sender: TField);
begin
  if Sender.AsString = 'x' then
    Sender.DataSet.Cancel;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;
  ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([1, 'a']);
  ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([2, 'b']);
  ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([3, 'c']);
end;
```

Compile, run, and enter 'x' (without the quotes) into the DBEdit.  Then click Save on the DBNavigator.

Notice that the edit is cancelled but the 'x' remains in the DBEdit.  This is
in Delphi 10.2.3, btw.  Back in D7 days, it was even worse - the wrong row in the
DB grid would show the 'x'!

The other thing is that `OnValidate` is never actually called in TDataSet's methods,
only descendants, e.g. TClientDataSet.  So there is no guarantee that in general
`OnValidate` will be called at all or at the right time - it's up to the dataset-type's author to get it right.

So I think the answer to your q is "No", leave the OnValidate to raise exceptions but no more.

Comment: Yes I lost a day trying to locate a very elusive error until I read these posts and changed OnValidate to OnSetSel and got everything working just fine.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me, the only purpose of `OnValidate` event is raising exceptions. From Delphi help (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Data.DB.TField.OnValidate):

> To reject the current value of the field from the OnValidate event
>   handler, raise an exception
>   ...
>   If writing the data does not raise an
>   exception, the OnChange event handler is called to allow a response to
>   the change.

For tasks of validation I use `OnSetText` event, which gives me possibility to silent restore original value if new one is not acceptable.

Comment: Remembering that `OnSetText` is not fired when the value is assigned directly to the field, without the use of a DBware control

Comment: @AnselmoMS, yes, it should be taken into account.